# Get index of first value above threshold in ordered list

Tags: python, list

I have a sorted list of values and I would like to return the index of the first value above a threshold. Is there a more pythonic way to return this value instead of looping through the list and checking each item?

```py
demo_list = [1, 1, 3, 5, 8, 13]
threshold = 4

## Some magic non-for-loop code here

## Returns 3 
## demo_list[3] == 5
```

Comment: check out binary search

Comment: Come on, don't know who closed it but linked answer is totally not related

Comment: use python bisect module=> bisect.bisect(demo_list, threshold)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not as optimal as a binary search, but you can do it in one fairly graceful line using a generator expression:

```
>>> demo_list = [1,1,3,5,8,13]
>>> threshold = 4
>>> next(i for i, v in enumerate(demo_list) if v > threshold)
3
```

Binary search is a little trickier, but more efficient if the list is very large:

```
>>> def first_over_ind(a, t, i=0) -> int:
...     if a[0] > t:
...         return i
...     mid = len(a) // 2
...     if a[mid] > t:
...         if a[mid-1] <= t:
...             return i + mid
...         return first_over_ind(a[:mid], t, i)
...     return first_over_ind(a[mid:], t, i + mid)
... 
>>> first_over_ind(demo_list, threshold)
3
```

Comment: For those looking for a threshold that is never met, use try/except statement to avoid a StopIteration error with the generator expression.

Comment: You can also just pass a default value to `next()`, e.g. `next((x for x in []), -1)`.